# How to disable dynamic workspaces and switch to fixed number via the shell?

Tags: command-line, gnome, workspaces

I can use this command to set the number of workspaces via shell:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 9
```

But I can't find the key to change it from **Dynamic workspaces** to **Fixed number of workspaces**.

How can I do that in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable dynamic workspaces:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false
```

To set a specific number of workspaces (e.g., 3 workspaces):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 3
```